# Python : using isinstance on C based type MatchObject

Tags: python, regex, isinstance

I'm working on a function in which i would like to know if an object is an instance of `re.MatchObject`. I tried to use `isinstance` but `re.MatchObject` is a C type and this does not work.

I still can do an alternative test like `hasattr( ... , 'pos')` or any other `re.MatchObject` attribute, but i don't consider it as a good solution.
Any other way ?

Comment: [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject). The real type name is `_sre.SRE_Match`

Comment: That the docs talk about `re.MatchObject` without there being a `MatchObject` name in `re` looks like a doc bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to use the proper type; the match object type is not explicitly importable, but you can use `type()` on an existing instance to store it:

```
import re

MatchObject = type(re.search('', ''))
```

then use that in `isinstance()` tests:

```
>>> MatchObject = type(re.search('', ''))
>>> isinstance(re.search('', ''), MatchObject)
True
```

There is nothing about C-defined Python types that prevents using `isinstance()` otherwise.